# How to make Joomla Intro Image Responsive in Blog Layout

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap, joomla

I wanna ask how to make Joomla Intro Image responsive. As I am dealing with dead end, I haven't succeed to make it responsive yet. I'm currently creating A Bootstrap Based Template Using Joomla 3.4.4

What I'm Trying to Do: 
[image]

But I Can't make The Intro Image Thumbnail responsive: 
[image]

Here's the code:

```html
<div class="news-item">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-offset-1">
      <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>"><h3 class="news-title"><?php echo $this->escape($this->item->title); ?></h3></a>
    </div>
  </div><br>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="hidden-xs col-sm-1">
      <span class="date"><?php echo JText::sprintf( JHTML::_('date',$this->item->publish_up, JText::_('d'))); ?></span><br><span class="month"><?php echo JText::sprintf( JHTML::_('date',$this->item->publish_up, JText::_('M'))); ?></span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3">
      <?php echo JLayoutHelper::render('joomla.content.intro_image', $this->item); ?>
</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8">
      <?php echo JHtmlString::truncate(strip_tags($this->item->text), 400); ?>
      <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>">Read More</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any advice will be greatly appreciated for this particular code:

```html
<?php echo JLayoutHelper::render('joomla.content.intro_image', $this->item); ?>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gw2 nice one :) but miss the old gw.

By the way, your code has not a container (or probably is before?) :

```
    <div class="news-item container">  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-offset-1">
      <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>"><h3 class="news-title"><?php echo $this->escape($this->item->title); ?></h3></a>
    </div>
  </div>  
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="hidden-xs col-sm-1">
      <span class="date"><?php echo JText::sprintf( JHTML::_('date',$this->item->publish_up, JText::_('d'))); ?></span>
      <br/>
      <span class="month"><?php echo JText::sprintf( JHTML::_('date',$this->item->publish_up, JText::_('M'))); ?></span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3">
      <?php echo JLayoutHelper::render('joomla.content.intro_image', $this->item); ?>
    </div> 
    <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8">
      <?php echo JHtmlString::truncate(strip_tags($this->item->text), 400); ?>
      <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>">Read More</a>
    </div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Also, you had a closing < /a> in the second row without an opening one. Moreover, you do not need a < br> after the first row, just remove it or replace with a clearfix div. If you need more space use css margin-bottom instead.

If you want to manage the intro image you can modify the html output looking at folder: template/your_template/html/layouts/joomla/content/intro_image or from root directory just layouts/joomla/content/intro_image

Hope it helps,
good luck!

Comment: ah yesss, the </a> after <?php echo JLayoutHelper::render('joomla.content.intro_image', $this->item); ?> what a clumsy me. Thank you very much for your advice, I really appreciate it. But I'm still struggling modifying the html output for the joomla intro image php code, I'll update the result laters. Cheers! Glad that you play GW series too ^.^

Comment: Oh My Gosh, I finally did it based on your instructions. I edited the root directory layouts/joomla/content/intro_image.php and added bootstrap class="img-responsive" It works like charm. Thank you very much! Problem Solved!

Answer (score 0):

It can be simply fixed with a single line of CSS:

```
img.[image-class]{ max-width:100%;}
```

If you have a live page or a Fiddle it will be easy to show you the fix.
Regards
*Nabeel*